# Getting the first element from <body> then insertBefore()

Tags: javascript, dom

I've been at this for a few hours now and am about to start ripping hair out. Basically what I need to do is get the first element that appears in the body and then insert another element before it.

I've tried the following to get the first element with no success (undefined or null)

```
window.document.body.firstChild

document.getElementsByTagName("body").firstChild

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].firstChild

window.document.documentElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[0]
```

And a whole slew of mixed and matched attempts of the previous snippets. I've also tried just getting the body then appendChild() with no success either.

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it in an iframe, or a normal document?

Comment: `document.body.firstChild` is fine. Are you sure you have the order of arguments to `insertBefore()` correct?

Comment: note firstChild will return the first node child it maybe text node or comment node or element or any other node, so if you going to append first element of the body better to use firstElementChild

Answer (score 15):

Yes, `document.body.firstChild` is correct. It's likely that you are overlooking the fact that [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore) is a method of the parent element, and it takes the new element before the existing one. For example:

```
var addedElement = document.createElement('p');
addedElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello, world!'));

var body = document.body;
body.insertBefore(addedElement, body.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 4):

You want something like this:

```
var first = document.body.children[0];
var beforeEle = document.createElement("div");
beforeEle.innerHTML = "I'm the first element in the body!";
document.body.insertBefore(beforeEle, first);
```

Comment: `children` is not universally supported (for example, it was introduced in Firefox only in version 3.5). You'll have to use `childNodes` for now.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution to prepend an element to the body I could up with is a one-liner:

```
document.body.insertBefore(element, dom.document.body.firstChild)
```